# Static Libraries and the statically-linked MSVC++ runtime

Tags: dll, runtime, static-libraries, static-linking, msvcrt

For building a `static library`, is the **static C runtime** statically linked at compile time (of the library) or at final EXE compile time?

Comment: Nothing is linked at compile time.  The CRT doesn't get linked until you link the final .exe or .dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Hans, the CRT (C Runtime) is not linked while compiling a static LIB using MSVC. It is linked at final EXE compile time.

However, even though this is true. You still cannot mix C runtimes in static libraries. They all must use the same exact runtime (or the system runtime MSVCRT.dll)